# Merging repeated items in a list into a python dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list that looks like the one bellow, with the same item of a pair repeated some times.

```
l = (['aaron distilled ', 'alcohol', '5'], 
['aaron distilled ', 'gin', '2'], 
['aaron distilled ', 'beer', '6'], 
['aaron distilled ', 'vodka', '9'], 
['aaron evicted ', 'owner', '1'], 
['aaron evicted ', 'bum', '1'], 
['aaron evicted ', 'deadbeat', '1'])
```

I would like to convert it to a list of  dictionaries in which I would merge all repetitions of the first item into one key, so the end result would look like:

```
data = {'aaron distilled' :  ['alcohol', '5', 'gin', '2',  'beer', '6', 'vodka', '9'], 
'aaron evicted ':  ['owner', '1', 'bum', '1', 'deadbeat', '1']}
```

I was trying something like:

```
result = {}
for row in data:
    key = row[0]
    result = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in data}
```

or

```
for dicts in data:
   for key, value in dicts.items():
    new_dict.setdefault(key,[]).extend(value)
```

But I get the wrong result. I am very new to python and would really appreciate any tip on how to solve this or reference to where to find the information that would allow me to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for ease:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for key, *values in data:
    result[key].extend(values)
```

Your first attempty will overwrite keys; a dict comprehension would not merge the values. The second attempt seems to treat the lists in the `data` list as dictonaries, so that wouldn't work at all.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> data = (['aaron distilled ', 'alcohol', '5'], 
... ['aaron distilled ', 'gin', '2'], 
... ['aaron distilled ', 'beer', '6'], 
... ['aaron distilled ', 'vodka', '9'], 
... ['aaron evicted ', 'owner', '1'], 
... ['aaron evicted ', 'bum', '1'], 
... ['aaron evicted ', 'deadbeat', '1'])
>>> result = defaultdict(list)
>>> for key, *values in data:
...    result[key].extend(values)
... 
>>> result
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'aaron distilled ': ['alcohol', '5', 'gin', '2', 'beer', '6', 'vodka', '9'], 'aaron evicted ': ['owner', '1', 'bum', '1', 'deadbeat', '1']})
```

Comment: or since it's Python3, `for k, *v in data: result[k] += v`

Comment: @gnibbler: also nice, I'll use that. :-)

Comment: If you want to avoid defaultdict, you can also use `result.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)` in the for-loop.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you so much for your help. I like this solution, but it creates one new problem for me, because the outcome is more difficult to sort. Is there a way to avoid `defaultdict` and to have an outcome that turn into tuples and to make it sortable? When I try to convert the `defauldict` object to tuples it creates like nested dictionaries that are hard to sort. I really appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: @user2962024: a `defaultdict()` is just a subclass of `dict` with one extra function; I am not certain what you want to sort here.

Comment: @koffein. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I would like to avoid defaultdict and go for a plain dict, but when I try to use the code you suggested, I still get a defaultdict. This is exactly what I am using: `result = defaultdict(list). I am obviously doing something wrong. Could you help me finding out what? Thanks!

for key, *values in data:
    result.setdefault(key, []).extend(values)`

Comment: @user2962024: just call `dict(result)` to turn a `defaultdict` back into a regular `dict`. You won't be able to sort it any better though.

Comment: @user2962024: I think you did not redefine `result` as a dict, thats why you got a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 1):

If the items in L are sorted by the first element you can use `groupby`

```
>>> L = (['aaron distilled ', 'alcohol', '5'], 
... ['aaron distilled ', 'gin', '2'], 
... ['aaron distilled ', 'beer', '6'], 
... ['aaron distilled ', 'vodka', '9'], 
... ['aaron evicted ', 'owner', '1'], 
... ['aaron evicted ', 'bum', '1'], 
... ['aaron evicted ', 'deadbeat', '1'])
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> {k: [j for a,b,c in g for j in b,c] for k, g in groupby(L, itemgetter(0))}
{'aaron evicted ': ['owner', '1', 'bum', '1', 'deadbeat', '1'], 'aaron distilled ': ['alcohol', '5', 'gin', '2', 'beer', '6', 'vodka', '9']}
```